# Race condition in Angular HTTP promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, angular-http

So, i have a small API interaction code that looks like this:

```
function load_posts() {
  return $http
    .get('/posts')
    .then(on_success);

  function on_success(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
}

function get_posts() {
  if (blog.posts) {
    return $q.when(blog.posts);
  }

  return load_posts().then(function (posts) {
    blog.posts = posts;

    return blog.posts;
  });
}
```

I do this to avoid hitting the API for the same results all the time. I have several separate directives and components that might need to call this API endpoint, but they don't need a fresh result everytime. But this results in an ugly race condition: if two or more components call the `get_posts` method before the `load_posts` response arrives, then they all issue API requests. There are no side-effects, because this is just a cache attempt, but it defeats the whole purpose.

Any ideas on how to proceed with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $http service can cache requests. [See here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Caching/) or the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for a deeper explanation of how the caching works.

> The default $http cache can be particularly useful when our data
>   doesn’t change very often. We can set it like so:
>
> ```
> $http({
>   method: 'GET',
>   url: '/api/users.json',
>   cache: true
> });
> // Or, using the .get helper
> $http.get('/api/users.json', {
>   cache: true
> });
> ```
>
> Now, every request that is made through $http to the URL
>   /api/users.json will be stored in the default $http cache. The key for
>   this request in the $http cache is the full-path URL.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a race-condition problem, it's just a matter of memoizing the function.  You can use something like `memoize()` from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or just implement it yourself:

```
var load_posts = () => {
  const p = $http
    .get('/posts')
    .then(response => response.data);
  load_posts = () => p;
  return p;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

1) Extract data retrieval into separate "blogService" service;

2) Cache promise in your service that does the request;

3) Return the same promise for all clients, you can manipulate results if you dont want to expose whole response object;

```
var promise = null;

function loadBlogs() {
    promise = promise || $http.get("/posts").then(function(response){return reponse.data;});
    return promise;
}
```

4) Then just call service method and wait for promise to resolve wherever you need (controller, directive, etc):

```
function getPosts() {
    blogService.loadBlogs().then(function (posts) {
        vm.posts = posts;
  });
```

Comment: I don't want to expose all of the internal response data to clients. That's why get posts is different than load posts.

Comment: Well, there is one subtle but important difference. In my answer I have emphasized that promise caching should be done in separate service (which would be singleton), not directly in controller or directive.

Comment: so, your code could be simply `var loadBlogs = (promise => () => promise = promise || $http.get('/posts').then(response => response.data))(null);
var getPosts = () => postService.loadBlogs(posts => blog.posts = posts);` ... just sayin

Comment: Can person downvoting this could at least spend a moment and explain why? @Jaromanda_X: What you say is true, but 1) shorter does not mean more readable, 2) not everyone can use new ES features and/or transpilers because different constraints  in project (mostly political, if you have worked with enterprise, you know what I mean)